# I have replaced the harddisk of my laptop . I need to get data from ext3 partitions of old harddisk.

Tags: mount, ext3

Unable to mount the partitions

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /media/sdb4 -t ext4
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
```

I get the output as below for command: `sudo fdisk -lu`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107860992 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773166 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d3c84

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848   204802047   102297600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       204804094   879108929   337152418    5  Extended
/dev/sdb4       879110144   976772253    48831055   83  Linux
/dev/sdb5       204804096   236923236    16059570+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       302471883   879108929   288318523+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       236924928   253643677     8359375   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb8       253644800   302471167    24413184   83  Linux
```

Comment: try once `gparted` or `Disk Utility` to mount your partition.. Reply..

Comment: Also, you said that partition fs type is ext3, but tried to mount it as ext4. They are different.

Comment: Try to detect the filesystem by content: `sudo file -s /dev/sdb4` also you can try to check the filesystem consistency: `sudo e2fsck -n /dev/sdb4` (with -n it will not make changes).